# break every 10rows and loop for new record

Tags: php

i have foreach  with the following data. Example thiis is thousands of record with unique ids and name.

```
IDS | NAMES

1   | name1
21  | name2
32  | name3
14  | name4
25  | name5
16  | name6
27  | name7
28  | name8
19  | name9
10  | name10
11  | name11
13  | name12
```

AND HOW I can ADD IDS AND NAMES IN EVERY 3 ROWS. like BELOW

```
IDS | NAMES
1   | name1
21  | name2
32  | name3

IDS | NAMES
14  | name4
25  | name5
16  | name6

IDS | NAMES
27  | name7
28  | name8
19  | name9

IDS | NAMES
10  | name10
11  | name11
13  | name12
```

Comment: you can just simply implement a counter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be close to your solution.

You need to implement counter

ex:

```
<?php $data=array(array('id'=>1,'name'=>'a'),
             array('id'=>1,'name'=>'a'),
             array('id'=>1,'name'=>'a'),
             array('id'=>1,'name'=>'a'),
             array('id'=>1,'name'=>'a'),
             array('id'=>1,'name'=>'a'),
             array('id'=>1,'name'=>'a'));

     //Your counter
     $cnt=3; //you can initialize as your requirement which here is 3

     foreach ($data as $d) {

         if ($cnt%3 == 0) {//Mode by your value which here is 3
             echo 'ID  |NAME<br/>';
         }
         echo $d['id'] . '|' . $d['name'] . '<br/>';

         $cnt++; //increment your counter
    }
```